# Firefox indexedDB not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, local-storage, indexeddb

I'm trying to identify if an user is in private/incognito browsing mode. So, I'm trying to get access to indexedDB to test private mode:

```
var is_private = false;
if (window.indexedDB && /Firefox/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
    var db;
    try {
        db = window.indexedDB.open('test');
    } catch(e) {
        is_private = true;
    }
}
```

On Firefox default version(non ESR), works fine: normal browsing `is_private` is `false` and on private mode `is_private` equals `true`.

But on Firefox ESR latest version always returns true even on normal browsing mode.

console.error on Firefox ESR returns this error from bellow print on `window.indexedDB.open('test')` line:

[image]

**EDIT:**
I write the js code bellow to get more details about the error exception:

```
var db = window.indexedDB.open('test');
db.onerror = function(event) {
    console.log(db.error);
});
```

The output is: `DOMError { name: "UnknownError", message: "The operation failed for reasons unrelated to the database itself and not covered by any other error code." }`

And in browser console:

```
console.log(window.indexedDB.open('test'));
```

Output is:
`IDBOpenDBRequest { onblocked: null, onupgradeneeded: null, source: null, transaction: null, readyState: "pending", onsuccess: null, onerror: null }`

Note that the **`readyState`** is always `"pending"`

Comment: Could be related to cookies: http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2012/04/25/firefox-failing-localstorage/ (in which case you can't use this to reliably detect private mode)

Comment: Or from your [html served locally](https://github.com/mozilla/chromeless/issues/149)? through file:// instead of the server ??

Comment: On normal firefox, non esr, works. But in Firefox ESR not. So, is not related to server.